# How To Forward Port From Arch Linux on Virtualbox?

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, arch-linux

I want to run [Visual Studio Code Server (code-server)](https://github.com/coder/code-server) on my Arch Linux VM (Virtualbox) under Windows 11 (Host). It runs fine, I can connect to the address on the Arch. But my main goal is to **access** it on Windows side, so the `code-server` lives on Arch, but I access it from Windows.

After some search, I found some articles that explain about **Port Forwarding** in Virtualbox. I followed them and set it up. Here is my network configuration in Virtualbox:

[Adapter Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFfQG.png)

[NAT Port Forwarding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjL3y.png)

On Arch, I ran `code-server` with `--bind-address` parameter to point it to `:2704`. It runs again, as expected. I was able to access it from Arch, but not on Windows. Accessed `127.0.0.1:7207` but it was showing error `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` or something like that. I've checked the firewall, Virtualbox and the browser are allowed to access under Public and Private Network.

[`code-server` Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bA0ng.png)

[`127.0.0.1:2704` on Arch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kv0wD.png)

[`127.0.0.1:7207` on Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GczPW.png)

Thank you. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Why not use Bridged Networking as that would give you and address on your router like any other real machine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've tried it but I can't connect to VM's IP address. Probably I missed something? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I managed to use "Bridged Adapter" (thanks to @John for the suggestion!) and forward `2704` port to my local with SSH.

1. Change network adapter to "Bridged Adapter" in VM configuration
2. Start `code-server` (you can also bind to another port)
3. Get VM's IP address by using `ip addr` command
4. Open Terminal / Windows Terminal on host machine, and issue:

   `ssh -N -L CodeServerPort:127.0.0.1:AnyPortYouWantToUse user@VM-IP`

   For example, for me:

   `ssh -N -L 2704:127.0.0.1:2704 hendramanudinata03@192.168.1.64`

   So what it does is forward VM's 2704 port to 127.0.0.1:2704 (localhost on port 2704) by using SSH.

Then you can access it on browser with `127.0.0.1:2704`.

Reference: https://coder.com/docs/code-server/latest/guide#port-forwarding-via-ssh

*Correct me if I made any mistake here so newcomers won't be confused :)*